# Java - what does annotation referencing itself do?

Tags: java, annotations

I stumbled across into the source code for the "Documented" Java Annotation recently.  It looks like this:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)
public @interface Documented {
}
```

What the purpose of "@Documented" within Documented itself?

Comment: What does the javadoc say?

Comment: The fact that the `Documented` annotation is annotated by itself doesn't mean anything special - it doesn't mean something different then when another annotation, class or interface is annotated with the `Documented` interface.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis this is not a duplicate. The linked question is about why self reference is possible in general and doesn't answer this question. This questions is about why this specific annotation type is annotated by itself.

Comment: @kapep That's explained by the javadoc but OP doesn't seem to think that's the answer. My interpretation of their question is about the self-reference itself. If you don't agree, vote to re-open. OP, if you think this isn't a duplicate, edit your question to clarify why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Documented.html):

> Indicates that annotations with a type are to be documented by javadoc and similar tools by default. This type should be used to annotate the declarations of types whose annotations affect the use of annotated elements by their clients. If a type declaration is annotated with Documented, its annotations become part of the public API of the annotated elements.

`@Documented` is a meta annotation - it annotates another annotation type. When an annotation type is annotated by `@Documented`, tools like javadoc should include the annotation when it is *used* somewhere in the code.

For example, the [`@Deprecated`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html) annotation type is annotated with `@Documented`. It's pretty important to know if something is deprecated, so `@Deprecated` is considered part of the public API and should be included in the documentation.

On the other hand, [`@SuppressWarnings`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) is just a hint for the compiler and not important for the API, so it is not annotated by `@Documented`.

The `@Documented` annotation type also annotates itself. Basically that just means that you will see any usage of `@Documented` in the documentation. This is done so that you can see if any annotation type will be documented or not.

Comment: That just says what the Annotation does, not the self-reference.  Are you saying that the self-reference just applies the annotation to itself?

Comment: @JoeG sorry is think i misread the question. The self reference is done because otherwise you wouldn't see that other annotation types use `@Documented`.